# How to get the activity result for barcode scanner android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, barcode, zxing

How to get the scanned barcode result for a custom scanner using zxing library ?  On activity result is not working. The scanning part is working fine and its getting the result. But I am not getting any data in the activity result.

```
public class ScannerActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

ResultHandler resultHandler;
Parameters parameters;
private CaptureManager capture;
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;
private Button switchFlashlightButton;
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
BarcodeView test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_scanner);

    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    resultHandler = (ResultHandler) extras.getSerializable("RESULT_HANDLER");
    parameters = (Parameters) extras.getSerializable("PARAMETERS");

    barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
    this.getIntent().putExtra("Result_handle",resultHandler);
    capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
    capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
    capture.decode();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult: .");
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        String re = scanResult.getContents();
        String message = re;
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult: ."+ re);
        Result handlerResult = new Result(Result.STATUS_SUCCESS, "qrcode", message);
        resultHandler.onHandleResult(handlerResult);
        this.finish();
    }
    // else continue with any other code you need in the method

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d("onResume", "onResume: .");
    super.onResume();
    capture.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("onPause", "onPause: .");
    super.onPause();
    capture.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    capture.onDestroy();
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d("onSaveInstanceState", "onSaveInstanceState: .");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

Comment: how do you send the results? please share your code

Comment: This is the result. But it comes from the CaptureManager.java class, which is a library  

          protected void returnResult(BarcodeResult rawResult) {
           Intent intent = resultIntent(rawResult, getBarcodeImagePath(rawResult));
        activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/journeyapps/barcodescanner/CaptureManager.java

Comment: I'm wondering whether there could be any conflict because you seem to ask for and receive results *in the same activity*. Normally ActivityA would "startActivityForResult(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);" and then AcitivtyB would (via "getIntent()") determine what it was supposed to do and finally call "setResult()" and "finish()". Then finally "onActivityResult()" of ActivityA would be called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it. This is how I did it.

I created a second activity CustomScannerActivity. In which I do the scanning part.

```
public class CustomScannerActivity extends Activity {

private CaptureManager capture;
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_scanner);

    barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
    capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
    capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
    capture.decode();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    capture.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    capture.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    capture.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Then from the first activity. I called the CustomScannerActivity from this one. So that now you will get the result. Hope it helps. Make sure that you declare the activities in the manifest also so that it will work.

```
public class ScannerActivity extends Activity {

ResultHandler resultHandler;
Parameters parameters;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(CustomScannerActivity.class);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult: .");
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        String re = scanResult.getContents();
        String message = re;
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult: ." + re);
        Result handlerResult = new Result(Result.STATUS_SUCCESS, "qrcode", message);
        resultHandler.onHandleResult(handlerResult);
    }
    // else continue with any other code you need in the method
    this.finish();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[[ FULL SOURCE CODE EXAMPLE ]](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/BarCodeQR)

You have give permission into manifesto file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERN
AL_STORAGE" />
```

And then add this following code in manifesto application tag:

```
<activity
            android:name=".encode.EncodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And then your onActivityResult() method will be look like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == 0) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            textViewFormat.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
            textViewData.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

            Uri imageURI = intent.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try{
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageURI);
                scannedBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT") + ":" + intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"), 5000).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            textViewFormat.setText("");
            textViewData.setText("Cancelled By user");
        }

    }
}


/**
 * This method used for converting BitMatrix to BitMap
 * @param matrix
 * @return bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap toBitmap(BitMatrix bitMatrix){
    int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

See my [git source code](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/BarCodeQR)

Comment: Please don't litter this forum with answers that do not address the problem.

Comment: there would be many problem in this application.... one would be in manufesto file and another would be the receiving the result.. I just tell him with the example.... and share my git link for more clarification... By the way thanks for your advice...